# Entries list without know ID of Category - want to usw category_url_title

Tags: channel-entries, entries, categories, segments

In my URL I have the category (segment_2).
And now I want a list with all entries from this category.

If I use category="8" its fine, but in my URL isn't a ID... it's the {category_url_title}.

{category_url_title} is my {segment_2}

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="redner" dynamic="off" category="{segment_2}" status="open"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

thanks for help
Michel

Answer (score 1):

if u want to use category_url_title in the title you must enable Use

> Category URL Titles In Links  In Admin ‣ Channel Administration ‣ Global Channel Preferences

as mention on http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html

and you must add the

> Category URL Indicator (default: "category")

in your URL so if your URL is http://example.com/page_name/your_category_url_title

then you must change it to http://example.com/page_name/category/your_category_url_title

In the otherhand IF you want to keep your URL as it you must use addons

a good one is http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat , so your code will be:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="redner" dynamic="off" category="{segment_2_category_id}" status="open"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Regard's.

Comment: thank you. The URL must be without "category", so I will try this addon :)

Comment: hi, if this works with you , please mark it as answer